# Some columns in report are not showing data on SSRS server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Please Help

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and SSRS to develop a report. I've created a stored procedure on the server and I am accessing it through the report. Within SSMS, the stored procedure runs and returns data just fine. Also, within Visual Studio I run the debug version of the report and it outputs data just fine.

The problem arises when I deploy the report and try to run it in the web portal. It runs without any errors and displays the report header, but there is no data in 2 columns out of 7 ! I've tried creating a new report accessing the same stored procedure and the same thing happens. What could cause this?

Comment: you really need to provide more information than that

Comment: Does it work via report designer in Visual Studio? Please provide screenshot of your dataset and tablix if possible.

Comment: Report is working fine in visual studio designer with proper values in all columns  but after report deployment data lost from 2 of its columns on SSRS server

Comment: Is it going off of the side of your page? Go into print preview to see if it shows up on any of the pages.

Answer (score 0):

A few possibilities;

1. The SPROC does not returns this data now and the report is only working in design view because it is using cached data (you can verify this by deleting the .data files in the report file directory and seeing if it stops working in design view)
2. You have a Shared Datasource configured which points to a different server/database on the report server than it does in Visual Studio, in that other server/database the sproc doesn't have data for those columns